# How to view the exact command cmake_automoc is running?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, cmake, moc

I have an issue with automoc in that moc fails with `Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"`. I tried the "least evil" hack outlined [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22829), but to no avail (speficially, I added `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC_MOC_OPTIONS "-DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED")` to my `CMakeLists.txt`). Further, when I try to moc the offending file myself, it seems to work.

I'd like to know the exact command CMake is running so I can continue debugging this. If I do `ninja -v`, however (equivalent of `make VERBOSE=1`), I get something like:

```
cd projdir && cmake -E cmake_automoc projdir/CMakeFiles/proj_automoc.dir/ Debug
```

If I run that myself, sure enough I get the same `Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"` message, but I still don't know how CMake is calling `moc`.

`cmake --debug-output -E cmake_automoc ...` throws a usage error.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have done the cmake configure step and generated the build scripts (eithe VS solution files or Unix makefiles), you can use cmake with the `build` option as described in the manual [cmake(1)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake.1.html#cmake-1). If you are using Makefiles, then you can use:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

For Visual Studio, see 
[Is there an option to produce more 'verbose' compiling?](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Is_there_an_option_to_produce_more_.27verbose.27_compiling.3F) for details.